# MongoDB aggregation joins

Tags: mongodb, join, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In a MongoDB database I've got two collections. One refers to another with an `id` string.

Collection `sessions` contains a field `session-id` and another one named `active`.

Collection `visits` contains a field `session-id`. Multiple visits refer to one session.

I want to drop all sessions where `active` is false, which is an easy task, but also all visits which refer to each dropped session.

Since there is no `JOIN` statement in MongoDB, how can I select all visits that should be dropped with one single command?

Can this be done with aggregation?

Comment: MongoDB does not do "joins", it should be a farly easy term to find in searching so you should stop looking since you have likely heard this before. If you have "related data" then is "should" ( where possible ) be contained in a single collection. Noting here that "possible" means that only the sheer size of related data should be stopping you from doing that. Instead you need to live with a "client join" where you need to retrieve the related data to the data you have queried, and "filter" there if required. Basically include "some related data" in the same collection. No join magic here.

Comment: Yeah, i put join in the title for searchability. Nevertheless: is it possible to use aggreagation for this? I'm strongly thinking about deleting this question, but I'll wait for a bit.

Comment: Then is was a bad choice that is likely to result in negative feedback. The basic rules here are that it is not possible to access more than one collection in a single request, and even bulk operations which can deal with many operations in a single request still need to be issued to one collection. So aggregate does not do joins, and mapReduce does not do joins either. There are simply no joins. You are "meant" to put the data in a single collection rather than many, which is why you should be using MongoDB and not a relational store. Or you live with multiple requests.

Comment: Face it. Not even a SQL relational store 'truly' does this in one request. It is only because of implemented "triggers" than you can do such things as "casade deletes" and other logic. MongoDB omits such "features" by design.

Comment: Or, to put it differently: MongoDB forces you to keep the applications logic where it belongs to.

Comment: While taking a walk I came up with the following thought, which I'll sum up as "aggregation-pipeline". Aggregate all inactive sessions, pipe them through another query. Implementing this (in the database) would take a lot of oomph out of the "no JOINs in here" discussion. While the application logic belongs into the application, it doesn't mean that the db shouldn't offer methods to accelerate certain commonly used tasks (accelerate in the context of c++ vs python + local vs remote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```js
// unordered bulk operations because basically we have 
// decoupled operations anyway
var bulkVisits = db.sessions.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()

// first, we need all inactive session IDs
var inactive_sessions = db.sessions.find({"active":"false"},{_id:1})

inactive_sessions.forEach(
  function(session){

    // queue the removal of visits which refer to inactive sessions...
    bulkVisits.find({"session-id":session._id}).remove();

  }
)

// ...execute the removal operations...
bulkVisits.execute()
// and remove the inactive sessions
db.sessions.remove({"active":"false"})
```

Comment: That's probably the way to do it. I'll half-heartedly accept this answer, because it is the "correct one" but this doesn't really solve the issue: be able to insert one single (bookmarkable) command into the MongoChef query field instead of having to use a python script to perform the task.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in aggregation

```
db.sessions.aggregate([ 
            $lookup :  {
                  from"visits",localField:"session-id", 
                  foreignField :"session-id",as : "},
{
$match : {"active" : true}}
])
```

Drop the result you get